# Rails: syck has been removed, psych is used instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych, syck

I receive this message during capistrano deploy of my rails project:

```
syck has been removed, psych is used instead
```

Versions:

```
gem 'rails', '=3.2.13'
ruby 2.0.0p247
```

As i know ruby use native yamler "Psych".

There is no any yamler in Gemfile.

In my boot.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This probably means that yamler is being assigned in a gem somewhere. You can see how the message is being generated here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8a896179ada36b4fc0f50d75500c801a3097924a/lib/yaml.rb

If yamler = 'syck' is called, the warning is produced.

I searched through my gems and found I had an older version of newrelic_rpm which had the following line which was causing the issue:
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck' if defined?(YAML::ENGINE)

Updating the newrelic gem fixed the issue for me. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my case it was gem 'vestal_versions'

Comment: Using a dichotomy method I tried removing different parts of my gems from Gemfile and found a gem that caused this exception.